# Is this a valid alternative to variance?

Tags: probability

So I read the reason we square the terms when we calculate variance, instead of using absolute values, is that it not only gives us an idea of how spread out the numbers are in relation to the mean (which is true in both cases) but also provides information about how spread they are between themselves.

My idea is to divide the information contained in the variance in two measurements:

1) Variance calculated with absolute values, in relation to the mean.

2) Variance calculated with absolute values, in relation to the variance of 1).

This way we don't loose information and we get more accurate and practical measurements, since squaring things is rather artificial.

Is this a good idea or am I missing something? I don't think having two measurements is a big disadvantage. Seems better to me than squaring things.

Comment: I've never heard of that being an advantage of variance vs. mean absolute deviation, and I'm not sure I understand how it gives us information on that or why it matters if it does. I always just thought of them as two different ways of measuring the size of the deviations from the mean ($L_2$ vs $L_1$ norm). The principal advantage of variance is that it has better theoretical properties, like additivity. I also don't understand your 2) "in relation to the variance of 1)" do you mean measure the deviations from the result of 1)?

Comment: I'll add that the 'theoretical advantages' are just that. Working with real data, $L_1$ has better robustness properties (and also using more robust measurements of central tendency, like median, is advisable). And the 'spread' property that variance and MAE measure is sometimes a red herring and easy to misinterpret (it doesn't characterize the tails well, for instance).